# Injector moduler error in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I am getting  "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]". Can anyone help me to solve this. My code is as follows..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
  max-width: 32em;
  margin: 1em auto 0;
}

img { width: 30px; }
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
// https://angular-ui.github.io/

// setup app and pass ui.bootstrap as dep
var myApp = angular.module("angularTypeahead", ["ui.bootstrap"]);

// define factory for data source
myApp.factory("States", function(){
  var states = ["Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Dakota", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"];

  return states;

});

// setup controller and pass data source
myApp.controller("TypeaheadCtrl", function($scope, States) {
    console.log("hello");
    $scope.selected = undefined;

    $scope.states = States;

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="angularTypeahead">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
        <h2><img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/15309/angular-logo.svg" alt="Angular.js Logo"> Angular.js Typeahead</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="states">Search for US States</label>
            <input name="states" id="states" type="text" placeholder="enter a state" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
        </div>
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I did wrong anywhere? I got this code from codepen. It is running perfectly there. But Its is not running in my local

Comment: Do inject ui.bootstrap files?

Comment: yes, it's probably what @hadiJZ said, do you have the [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) files in your project?

Comment: Add [ui-bootsrtap](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-bootstrap) and its [dependencies](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started)

Comment: The ui bootstrap scripts are missing.

Comment: Thanks.. Its working after adding ui bootstrap files. But the typeahead is not coming.. Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: @SanthoshAineri use unminified version of angular.js for better debug view.